# Highcharts column range type doesn't accept date/time series?

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I am trying to plot through a column range chart, the sleeping times of people (my y).

My series of data consist in the sleep time and wake up time every day (my x axis).
I tried modifying the example given for column range but as soon as I put a date in the series instead of plain number, the graph doesn't show.

I use the code below - appreciate your input on this.

Thanks

```
  $(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Sleeping time per day'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Observed in 2013'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['02/07/2013', '03/07/2013', '04/07/2013']
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Time'
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Leo',
        data: [
            [date.UTC(2013,07,02,21,0,0), date.UTC(2013,07,03,4,0,0)],
            [date.UTC(2013,07,02,21,0,0), date.UTC(2013,07,03,5,0,0)],
            [date.UTC(2013,07,02,21,0,0), date.UTC(2013,07,03,6,0,0)]
        ]
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Date` object, instead of `date`.

http://jsfiddle.net/XBmB5/